# Change input placeholder * color only

Tags: html, css, input, placeholder

I have multiple input fields some fields are `required` and required field mention with `*` so I need to change input placeholder `*` color only, **not change whole placeholder color** check below image what I exactly need.

[image]

I have tried below code to achieve this but it can change whole color of placeholder

```css
div {
  margin:10px 0px;
}
input {
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #8d97a0;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name *">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="Email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password *">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #999 6em, red 5em);
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  font-family: monospace;/* less surprise about length of text at screen */
}
input {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  height:20px;
  padding:10px;
  border: none;
  display: block;
outline:none;

}
input:invalid {/* color part of text only when placeholder is shown */
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input placeholder="Password *" required />
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this...You can achieve your requirement using `:before and :after` and for input tag there is no support of `:before and :after`. So you can do it by adding label to your input and give `:before and :after` CSS to label

```css
input {
    width: 160px;
}

input[required] + label {
    color: #999;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: .8em;
    position: relative;
    left: -166px; /* the negative of the input width */
}


input[required] + label:after {
    content:'*';
    color: red;
}
/* show the placeholder when input has no content (no content = invalid) */
input[required]:invalid + label {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* hide the placeholder when input has some text typed in */
input[required]:valid + label{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="password" id="name" name="name" required="required" />
    <label for="name">Password</label>
```

Comment: I've tried this also but I don't have to use `label` and `required` in input

Comment: Consider specifying vertical bar cursor for that label, to be consistent with what users see and expect from hovering the cursor over an input field.

Answer (score 2):

Just `placeholder` wont give different `styles`.If you want different style you need to separate like this.

```css
input {
    width: auto;
}

input + label {
    color: #999;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: .8em;
    position: relative;
    left: -166px; 
}

input[required] + label:after {
    content:'*';
    color: red;
}


input[required]:invalid + label {
    display: inline-block;
}

input[required]:valid + label{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required" />
  <label for="name">Password</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried this already but I don't have to use label and required in input

Answer (score 2):

**See This:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.colorHolder').click(function(){
        $('.havePlace',this).focus();
    })
    
    $('.havePlace').on('input',function(){
        var len = ($(this).val()).length;
        if (len)
            $(this).next('label').hide();
        else
            $(this).next('label').show();
    })
    
})
```

```css
input {
    width: 150px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #8d97a0;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}

.colorHolder {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.colorHolder .havePlace + label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 7px;
    bottom: 2px;
    color: #CCC;
    cursor: text;
}

.colorHolder .havePlace + label:after {
    content: '*';
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<div  class="colorHolder">
    <input type="password" name="password" class="havePlace">
    <label>Password </label>
</div>

<div  class="colorHolder">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="havePlace">
    <label>Email </label>
</div>

<div  class="colorHolder">
    <input type="text" name="text" class="havePlace">
    <label>Text </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Need all `*` comes in end not in start. I need exactly above image which I uploaded you changed UI

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use span in the placeholder so you can change the color of *

```js
$(function() {
    $(".holder + input").keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val().length) {
            $(this).prev('.holder').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).prev('.holder').show();
        }
    });
    $(".holder").click(function() {
        $(this).next().focus();
    });
});
```

```css
.holder {
position: absolute;
margin: 5px 5px;
cursor: auto;
font-size: 11pt;
z-index: 1;
}
.red{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="holder">Email Adress <span class="red">*</span></div>
<input id="input" size="18" type="text" />
```

credits: [Add span inside form's placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415875/add-span-inside-forms-placeholder)

Answer (score 1):

With the current markup I don't think this is possible with just CSS, but:

This **is possible** if it's ok to add a `label` element after the input - like so:

```
<div>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder=" " />
  <label for="password">Password</label>
</div>
```

### [**Codepen demo**](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/dZoMvP?editors=1100)

The trick here is to use the pseudo class:

### [:placeholder-shown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown) ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder-shown))

From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#placeholder):

> Input elements can sometimes show placeholder text as a hint to the
>   user on what to type in. See, for example, the placeholder attribute
>   in [HTML5]. The **:placeholder-shown** pseudo-class matches an input
>   element that is showing such placeholder text.

The idea here is for the text "**Password ***" to *simulate* placeholder text.

Placeholders are always shown on `input` elements - even if they are focused - unless a value is set on them.

By using the `:placeholder-shown` pseudo class on the `input` - we can determine when to display the label text.

This is the key selector:

```
input:placeholder-shown + label {
  display: block;
}
```

This means: when the input's placeholder is shown - show the "placeholder" label. (otherwise we hide it)

For this reason we still need to set a non-empty placeholder attribute on the input (a simple whitespace is sufficient)

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
label {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  left: 5px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #757575;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: system-ui;
}
label:after {
  content: " *";
  color: red;
}
input:placeholder-shown + label {
  display: block;
}
input {
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #8d97a0;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="password" name="name" id="name" placeholder=" " />
  <label for="name">Name</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="password" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Email" />
</div>

<div>
  <input type="password" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Phone" />
</div>

<div>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder=" " />
  <label for="name">Password</label>
</div>
```

### **[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/dZoMvP?editors=1100)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't use this I have multiple fields and all fields are not `required[*]`

Comment: This has nothing to do with required, the only question is whether you can add an extra element after the input

Comment: Thanks! but placeholder and label are not looking same **replace Phone to Password**  then you can get what I mean so please can you check this.

Comment: I tried to change `font-size` placeholder and  label but still not coming same