# fontawesome user in placeholder

Tags: html, css, icons

How To Put fontawesome in placeholder. Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">         
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="username" id="inputdefault" type="text" />
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="password" id="inputdefault" type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: A possible workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/36808965/2375207

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```css
input {
  padding:10px;
 font-family: FontAwesome;
   
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control empty" id="iconified" placeholder="&#xf2ba">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: do I need to import something

Comment: @Ephraim just your font awesome library you need to include which is expected.  Here I have included font awesome CDN link. That's it.

Comment: @Ephraim have you added the CSS  which I have given ? `font-family: FontAwesome;`

Comment: @Ephraim box is coming because you have not included the font-awesome in `font-family` which can be done by the CSS I have provided.

Comment: @Ephraim Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="&#xF002;" id="inputdefault" style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome" />
```

A list of hex codes can be found in the [Font Awesome cheatsheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/).