# Adding asterisk after input field using Bootsrap 3 and AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

```
<div class="form-group form-group-lg">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{translation.FIRST_NAME}}:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10 required">
        <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" ng-model="Addressid.nameFirst" ng-minlength="3" placeholder="First Name" required>
        <div ng-messages="rmaForm.firstName.$error">
            <div ng-message="required">
                Please enter your first name
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.required:after { content:" *"; }
```

**Question**

I know how to get asterisk after a label, but I want it to be after the Input fields. At the moment it is after the error message in second div. Is this possible with CSS to get it after a input field?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197671/use-css-to-automatically-add-required-field-asterisk-to-form-inputs/11197803#11197803

Comment: My problem is that there is another div inside the first div, so the asterisk goes after that and I don't want that. So partly this is duplicate, partly not.

Comment: That's why I linked it as a **possible** duplicate. If I'd actually voted to close it it would have been 'gold-badge hammered' and closed.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>What about</strike>

```
.required input:after {
  content: " *";
}
```

Just realised you can't put an after on an input field. The best way would be a span, which could even be added by javascript on every .required field:

```
$('.required input').after('<span class="asterisk">*</span>');
```

This would automate the task, which could come in handy

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for example

```
.required:after {
  content: " *";
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 190px;
}
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ztscnqwj/))

Or you just add a new `span` after the input and put the asterix in:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" ng-model="Addressid.nameFirst" ng-minlength="3" placeholder="First Name" required>
<span class="required-field">*</span>
```

Comment: Problem with your html approach is that * is displayed in next line

Answer (score 0):

This is what you wanted [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a1kkLaj8/)

```
.required:after {
  content: " *";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 6px;
}
```

Comment: But in my case there is an another div inside the first one, so this is not working.