# How can I add red asterik in @Html.Label

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

@Html.Label("YourProperty")

I wanted to make the above label as required. I know how to achieve that in @Html.LabelFor as below:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedLocations.LocationList, true)
```

Could anyone please suggest how can I get the required property in @Html.Label? I just wanted to add a red asterisk in above label.

Comment: In general input fields would be marked as required, not static labels.

Comment: Labels aren't form elements.  They do not support being "required”

Comment: What would you be requiring on a label?  It's a display element and not an input element - you can't require that someone sees something haha

Comment: I just needed to put the red asterik mark infront of label

Comment: @GagandeepSinghRandhawa the asterisk should generally be in front of the input that the label is referring to - the required attribute on the label will not generate that, you need to put it on the input itself.

Comment: How can I get that. Could you please provide an example

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197671/use-css-to-automatically-add-required-field-asterisk-to-form-inputs

Comment: See the duplicate link i just added.  You need to write a custom HtmlHelper that will read the required attribute of the model field.